# Error restoring Site collection from a different farm

Tags: sharepoint

Using restore-spsite I get the error:

> restore-spsite : The extension
>   Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.ProjectDatabaseExtension
>   is of version 16.1.293.0, and the backup was on version 16.1.287.0.
>   These versions are incompatible. At line:1 char:1

My SharePoint is not a project server. and the CU is the latest.
Does it mean the backup should be from a SharePoint with latest CU too?

Comment: You have to have exact same CU version installed on your server as the backup. So in your case you need to upgrade the server backup was made to your server version, create backup and then restore your spsite from correct backup.

Comment: The farm I restore to is with no CUs at all but the Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.ProjectDatabaseExtension is of version 16.1.293.0 newer the the source that is on FP2 16.1.287.0                        both were installed from the same ISO. I am sure it has to do with the automatic update.

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to get this to work, by editting/changing the minor version WTHIN the backup file (using a Hex editor, I used HxD)

In my case I had the following error:

> restore-spsite : The extension
>   Microsoft.Office.Project.Server.Database.Extension.ProjectDatabaseExtension
>   is of version 16.1.**309**.0, and the backup was on version
>   16.1.**303**.0. These versions are incompatible.

I only changed **303** (my source farm version) in **309** (my target farm version)
(The version data is on the begin of the backup file)

ps: None of the farms I work with uses Project Server and all SharePoint Server versions are x.0.x.x and not x.1.x.x